# Charging a LiPo using Battery Protection Circuit

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-operated, lipo

I have an application where I power an ESP32 from a LiPo battery. Between the LiPo and the ESP32, I have a DW01A battery protection circuit (data sheet is here: https://hmsemi.com/downfile/DW01A.PDF).

The DW01A has overcharge protection built into it.

When I connect the ESP32's USB port while also having the battery connected, the voltage on the battery connector (on the protected side of the DW01A) raises to ~4.2V.

Can I thus safely use the ESP32's USB port to charge the battery? Or is more charging circuitry required, than only the battery protection circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is adequate for No-load charging. But if used with load, then load current must be sensed so that it does not dwell on CV stage (4.2) (which ages battery) and only used below 3.8V for CC mode and CV mode with extra regulator and control from Load V,I sensing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This helps a lot!